# Sendmail not able to send to Gmail accounts

Tags: email, sendmail

I'm running a small IRCd on a vps. No firewall. When users register their nicks, a confirmation email is sent out to them by `Sendmail` to the email address they entered during registration. All but Gmail users get email. I found [this](https://support.google.com/a/answer/4568483) and made an spf record using my IP address and placed it my MX record:

```
"v=spf1 ip4:168.235.75.84 include:_spf.google.com ~all"
```

But Gmail emails still aren't received. Here's some text from `/var/mail/root`

```
----- The following addresses had permanent fatal errors -----
<email.address@gmail.com>
(reason: 550-5.7.1 [2604:180:3:284::8c64] Our system has detected that this message does)

----- Transcript of session follows -----
... while talking to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.:
>>> DATA
<<< 550-5.7.1 [2604:180:3:284::8c64] Our system has detected that this message does
<<< 550-5.7.1 not meet IPv6 sending guidelines regarding PTR records and
<<< 550-5.7.1 authentication. Please review
<<< 550-5.7.1  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=ipv6_authentication_error for more
<<< 550 5.7.1 information. hn5si5276310pac.203 - gsmtp
554 5.0.0 Service unavailable

--u4AMhua5032690.1462920236/xtremeirc.net
Content-Type: message/delivery-status

Reporting-MTA: dns; xtremeirc.net
Received-From-MTA: DNS; localhost.localdomain
Arrival-Date: Tue, 10 May 2016 18:43:55 -0400

Final-Recipient: RFC822; email.address@gmail.com
Action: failed
Status: 5.7.1
Remote-MTA: DNS; gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com
Diagnostic-Code: SMTP; 550-5.7.1 [2604:180:3:284::8c64] Our system has detected that this message does
Last-Attempt-Date: Tue, 10 May 2016 18:43:56 -0400

--u4AMhua5032690.1462920236/xtremeirc.net
Content-Type: text/rfc822-headers

Return-Path: <root@xtremeirc.net>
Received: from xtremeirc.net (localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1])
    by xtremeirc.net (8.14.4/8.14.4/Debian-8) with ESMTP id u4AMhsa5032688;
    Tue, 10 May 2016 18:43:55 -0400
Received: (from root@localhost)
    by xtremeirc.net (8.14.4/8.14.4/Submit) id u4AMhsQs032687;
    Tue, 10 May 2016 18:43:54 -0400
Date: Tue, 10 May 2016 18:43:54 -0400
From: root <root@xtremeirc.net>
Message-Id: <201605102243.u4AMhsQs032687@xtremeirc.net>

--u4AMhua5032690.1462920236/xtremeirc.net--
```

For what it's worth, I have an IPv6 address set up for my domain.

I'm out of my league on this and don't know what I'm doing wrong here? If I need to post more information, please advise. Thanks.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler - i just used that website and verified my IP (168.235.75.84) and the domain name with both IPv4 and IPv6. So I don't understand what you say I'm missing.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler - I see what you're saying now. That used to be the IPv6, but I took it out a month or so ago. Just today I added `2604:180:3:284:10:e1e2:ac2d:20` for AAAA record. If you use that on the website you provided, it resolves to xtremeirc.net. That said, what can I do so that gmail sees it as well? And will I also need to change the`spf` rule to IPv6 instead of IPv4?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler - Since this is a new AAAA record, only an hour old or so, maybe it hasn't had time to resolve. Once it resolves, will I be okay? Or do I have to use `2604:180:3:284::8c64`? irc.xtremeirc.net uses the other IPv6 `2604:180:3:284:10:e1e2:ac2d:20` for IPv6 connections to the IRCd. And since I had removed `2604:180:3:284::8c64` a month or so ago, I put IPv6 `2604:180:3:284:10:e1e2:ac2d:20` in for the AAAA record. Or do I need to change that back to `2604:180:3:284::8c64`?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler - The IPv6 address I showed you got chopped off. Please try `2604:180:3:284:10:e1e2:ac2d:2016`. That said, since it resolves to xtremeirc.net, will it also eventually be seen by Gmail instead of the other IPv6?

Comment: Ahh, it was chopped off. OK yes that does have valid reverse DNS entries. "*will it also eventually be seen by Gmail"* - still nope. GMail is looking at your TCP connection and the IP address you are connecting from. Then it does a reverse-DNS lookup on that. You appear to be actually connecting from 2604:180:3:284::8c64 (from the error log), and not from the new IP you describe. That's a matter of network settings on your server (eth0 IP address or sendmail configuration or routing or whatever), and no DNS change will affect that.  You removed it but you're still using it...?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler - Even though I have irc.xtremeirc.net set to `2604:180:3:284:10:e1e2:ac2d:2016`, can I also have `2604:180:3:284::8c64` set to xtremeirc.net? Doing this seems it wld create a conflict. If so, where wld I find the network setting of `2604:180:3:284::8c64` so I can change it to `2604:180:3:284:10:e1e2:ac2d:2016` so Gmail wld see that instead?

Comment: You typically have one A and AAAA entry on a domain -> IP address. You can have one PTR entry going IP -> domain on any number different IP addresses all resolving back to the same domain without any significant problems. As to where you find the network setting - uhh, well it's in your VPS's operating system network configuration ... but why not keep using the one you are using and put the DNS right for that?

Comment: That's what I asked you. Can I have one IPv6 for irc.xtremeirc.net and yet another for xtremeirc.net without them conflicting since irc.xtremeirc.net is just a subdomain of xtremeirc.net? If I can do this, then I'll change xtemeirc.net back to what gmail is looking for. Please advise.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler - Kept irc.xtremeirc.net IPv6 same and changed xtremeirc.net back to old IPv6...and now Gmail gets mail from my server.  Thanks for all your help. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your SPF record should include your IPv6 address.

```
"v=spf1 ip4:168.235.75.84 ip6:2604:180:3:284::8c64 include:_spf.google.com ~all"
```